# Free expansion and the Kelvin/Clausius statements of the 2nd law

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

It is perfectly possible to have a thermally-isolated gas expanding freely into a vacuum, as in the Joule expansion. And yet, if we were to film the process and then play it back in reverse, we witness a process that is never observed in nature.

Is it possible to explain the impossibility of the backwards process by showing that it would violate either the Kelvin or the Clausius statements of the 2nd law of thermodynamics?

Comment: Would it satisfy your requirements to show that the reverse process would result in an decrease in the entropy of the universe?

Comment: @ChesterMiller I'm looking for an argument that doesn't invoke entropy. Since the concept of entropy owes its existence to the Kelvin/Clausius statements, they should be adequate to explain the irreversibility of the process.

Comment: Well, if you can make the connection between Kelvin/Clausius and entropy, and you can show that, for this particular process, entropy decreases, then that should do it.  Irreversibility of a process is directly connected to entropy increase.

Comment: I suppose so! Well, I guess that's my next bit of homework.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very well-phrased answer to this exact question in Planck's treatise on thermodynamics.

If the reverse process of a free expansion were possible, you could arrange the following cycle: allow a gas to expand isothermally against some pressure, consuming a quantity of heat then delivering all of it as work to the surroundings. Then reverse the process using the "reverse" free expansion, for which q=0 and w=0. Then lather rinse and repeat, and you've got an engine converting heat fully into work with no other changes, violating the Kelvin statement of the second law.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only say it is statistically "impossible" due to the bulky nature of this experiments. If the observation of such phenomenon goes to small scales where statistical fluctuation comes into play and you may want to refer to Crook's Fluctuation theorem. The fluctuation contains certain actions in the system to "violate" the 2nd law, but the 2nd law is still statistically valid if you average over all actions.

Please refer to the classical paper by G.E.Grooks:

[The Entropy Production Fluctuation Theorem and the Nonequilibrium Work Relation for Free Energy Differences](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9901352)

Also please correct me if you can any mistakes in my answer.

Comment: Surely there must be a simpler explanation that doesn't invoke statistical mechanics. 

Take, for example, the transfer of heat from a hot body to a cold body. In the forward process, a quantity of heat, q, flows from a hot body to a colder body with no other changes. Such a process is NOT prohibited by the Clausius statement (heat can't flow from cold to hot with no other accompanying changes), so it occurs

But if we watch that process backwards on a videotape, we'd be witnessing a quantity of heat, q, flowing from cold to hot with no accompanying changes, violating Clausius statement.

Comment: Can we not make a similar, simple argument showing that the exact reverse process of a free expansion is impossible?

Comment: However, if we go to inspect the phenomena of this kind to micro-scale, there is indeed a non-zero probability for the reverse process to happen. I think the Clausius statement does not include this fact. And this probability of reverse work can be measured in papers such as:http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v437/n7056/abs/nature04061.html . Therefore, I believe taking the limit of Crooks Fluctuation theorem to the macroscopic scale, you can say the reverse has the probability of zero.

Answer (score 0):

If a spontaneous reversal of free expansion of a thermally isolated gas were possible then one could place a piston in front of the expanding gas to get net work out of it in cycles (we can design a mechanism that takes out work both during expansion and its reversal). This net work may be utilized to drive heat from colder to hotter body. This violates Clausius statement because the process, considered as a whole, is spontaneous.

Comment: The expanding gas does no work since it is a free expansion.

Comment: @Rogworth My point is you can get work out of it. For example free flow of heat from hotter to colder body does no work, unless you insert a heat engine in between.